# How does a CMS work ? How to add articles and manage them?

Tags: entries

I would like to design a news outlet website, if that's the correct name.

I've drawn a little sketch and I have a pretty good idea about the user interface; things like the site logo, nav-bar, content placement, footer, the easy stuff.

The thing that I don't understand is how does content management work?. I assume that I don't make a webpage.html for each article, right ? And if that's the case, then I am sure that there are other optimized methods of doing this. How will that work ? Let's say that a user clicks on a preview (that's on the first page), where do I send him if I assume that I don't make websites for each article ?

Also, how can I make a top 100 articles based on a marking of my own choosing; example: game reviews with scores from 0 to 100; if a user clicks on Top 100 Games I would like to present him with an ordered list of the top 100 games reviewed by my website.

What about auto-arranging the articles in a chronological order in a specified `[div][/div]` ? For example: the last five written articles presented chronologically in the middle of the screen from left to right.

I would prefer to design this website using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP, without using platforms like WordPress. This is because I have never used WordPress.

Any advice is welcomed. I have never done such a big project before. I've mainly done simple websites for my job. This is a project form which I hope I can learn lots of new stuff.

Also, please do give me advice if you think that implementing my idea into WordPress is easier than doing it from the ground-up. I mean, I am pretty sure that it's easier, but I haven't used it before and I don't know if I can customize it to my heart's content. I assume that, when using WordPress, you select a "News" Theme that has a built-in CMS for your site which gives you, let's say, a slideshow that arranges the articles in a chronological order. Now, what if I want to change that slideshow into a design of my own ? How do I take take the CMS from point A and implement it over point B ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange, @GeorgicaFaraFrica! This question doesn't seem to be specific to Craft CMS, so I'm going to move it to a more appropriate Stack Exchange site. If you have any more questions specifically about Craft CMS, please post them! :)

Answer (score 2):

Creating a website in Craft CMS as you outline requires a fair bit of knowledge:

- HTML
- CSS
- Tag language, like Twig (which is what Craft CMS uses)
- Maybe a little JavaScript
- Basics of file management, FTP (or version control)

Wordpress is a tool that *may* allow you to create your site with less knowledge of the above - there are pros and cons to each approach.

If you have knowledge of the above skills, I suggest watching some basic Craft tutorials, at [Mjingo](https://mijingo.com), for example, installing Craft on a local or remote server, and learning the basics. Then you will know if it is the right tool for you.

[Here's a big list of Craft resources](https://github.com/craftcms/awesome).